# css divs wrap across columns

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to make a column of tiles similar to masonry without actually having to load another JS plugin.  I guess as a last resort I could.  My problem right now is that the div's inside my column container get wrapped across if they're long.

see my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dLM6A/3/

Note the blue tile is spanning across the columns.  Is there some way to force it to remain in the same column?

HTML

```
    <form id="member-form" class="form-standard" action="" method="post">
    <div id="Misc" class="tile-columns">
        <div class="tile">
             <h2 class="tile-title">Notes</h2>

            <textarea id="Notes" name="Notes"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="tile" style="background: #5fe;">
             <h2 class="tile-title">Info</h2>

            <div class="field-section">
                <label for="SecQuestion1">Question 1</label>
                <textarea id="SecQuestion1" name="SecQuestion1"></textarea>
                <label for="SecQuestion1Answer">Answer</label>
                <input id="SecQuestion1Answer" name="SecQuestion1Answer" type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="field-section">
                <label for="SecQuestion2">Question 2</label>
                <textarea id="SecQuestion2" name="SecQuestion2"></textarea>
                <label for="SecQuestion2Answer">Answer</label>
                <input id="SecQuestion2Answer" name="SecQuestion2Answer" type="text" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
             <h2 class="tile-title">Reference</h2>

            <textarea id="Reference" name="Reference"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
             <h2 class="tile-title">Another Tile</h2>

            <p>More Content Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end columns -->
</form>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family:"roboto condensed";
    font-size: 12px;
}
h2.tile-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.tile {
    background: #ffffff;
}
.tile, .tile-notice {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.tile-columns {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 1;
    width: 689px;
}
.tile-columns .tile {
    width: 323px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.form-standard .field-section {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.form-standard label, .form-standard input, .form-standard textarea {
    display: block;
}
.form-standard input {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
}
.form-standard textarea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To force the content to remain in the same column (not break across columns), I added the following lines to your `.tile` class (you could add them elsewhere if you wanted):

```
break-inside: avoid-column;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

This worked in Chromium and Firefox (I do not have IE to test, but [it should work back to IE 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-page-break)). You can see the results in an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dLM6A/11/

You can read about the `page-break-inside` property here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp